# PHP Arrays - Optimization

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

A left rotation operation on an array of size n shifts each of the array's elements 1 unit to the left. For example, if 2 left rotations are performed on array [1,2,3,4,5], then the array would become [3,4,1,2,3].
I am trying to find the most efficient way to solve the below problem. The first line contains two space-separated integers denoting the respective values of n  (the number of integers) and d (the number of left rotations you must perform). 
The second line contains n space-separated integers describing the respective elements of the array's initial state.

Example input:

```
5 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Example Output:

```
5 1 2 3 4
```

In most cases, my below code works well, but in terms of execution time, there seems to be some room for improvement - it is currently failing one test with a very large input file (see below) due to Timeout.

My question is, what can be done to reduce the execution time of the below piece of code?

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents ("php://stdin","r");
$file = explode("\n",$file);

$meta = explode(" ", $file[0]);
$rotations = $meta[1];

$nums = explode(" ", $file[1]);

while($rotations > 0) {
    $removed = array_shift($nums);
    $nums[] = $removed;
    --$rotations;
}

echo implode(" ", $nums);

?>
```

Large Input File

[Input File](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/24100/input08.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1486829605&Signature=CXc9Y6Gro7aDaYt9VsyLgwgn9II%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

Comment: Which proposed solution are you comparing against?

Comment: Which suggestion proposed by whom? Are you referring to any of your earlier questions? What is it that you _are_ asking of us, "optimize this code for me"?

Comment: @CodeCaster, see edited.

Comment: *it is currently failing one test* - how it fails? execution time, memory exhausted ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, execution time. It is being tested using an online compiler. I am not sure what memory / execution time limit they have set, but it shows "Terminated Due to Timeout", for the test case using the input file in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User array_slice

```
array array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length = NULL [, bool $preserve_keys = false ]] )
```

Pseudocode:

```
// you are given: $array_size, $rotation, $input_array;
$rotation = $rotation % array_size;
$slice_place = $array_size - rotation;

$answer = []
if(rotation>0) {
    $array1 = array_slice($input_array, $slice_place, $rotation)
    $array2 = array_slice($input_array, 0, $slice_place)
    $answer = array_merge($array1, $array2)
}
else {
    $answer = $input_array
}
```

Comment: this does not answer the question, please explain

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you please explain why your code may work and why your proposed implementation is more efficient?

Comment: @GeorgeCastan100 your code has complexity O(rotation) each of each include such operation as array_shift which is O(size_array). In total O(rotation*size_array), mine is three operation of complexity O(size_array), thus it is O(size_array) =)

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful!

Comment: @GeorgeCastan100 the reason is that array_shift not only shifts the order but changes keys (implicitly hidden for each element of array).

Comment: @GeorgeCastan100: to perform r rotation, his code only using 1x time rotation calculation O(n), but your code run using r rotation which lead to complexity  O(n * r).

Comment: Thanks @algojava, this now makes sense :)